# Freeform in Quickfixj Banzai client

Tags: quickfixj

I am trying to simulate a buy side client who could send order to an exchange, receive execution reports and further cancel / replace orders. QuickfixJ Banzai swing based UI seems like an ok fit given it’s free and our startup doesn’t want to spend a lot of money for this.

Currently the Benzai UI only has specific text boxes to send orders with fields for symbol, qty etc. I was wondering if someone has come across an extension to this swing UI example which takes messages in a freeform text area so that we are not limited by the number of economic fields  exposed in the UI and could send any other fix messages in the text area.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool that comes to my mind is http://fixpusher.sourceforge.net/

AFAICT it is not maintained anymore and probably is capable of more than what you want.

But if you have a little of Java coding experience, how hard can it be to add a text box  to Banzai and call `MessageUtils.parse()` on its contents?

Comment: Thanks @Christoph. Yes, Banzai is nice as I can easily extend the functionality and add features like freeform in Swing. But I was thinking if someone had already added some functionalities to make it more useful as a FIX testing client instead of reinventing the wheel.  I am now using fixpusher - it seems great for what I was looking for. thanks!